# What is the most efficient method to do a list comparison between a simple list A and a list of list B?

Tags: list, python-2.7, comparison, python-itertools

I have list A:

```
['0.0720', '0.0200', '0.0260', '0.0210', '0.0740', '0.0510', '0.0160']
```

and also list B:

```
[
[0.074, 0.073, 0.072, 0.03, 0.029, 0.024, 0.021, 0.02], 
[0.02, 0.015], [0.026, 0.02, 0.015], 
[0.021, 0.02, 0.017], 
[0.077, 0.076, 0.074, 0.055, 0.045, 0.021], 
[0.053, 0.052, 0.051, 0.023, 0.022], 
[0.016]
]
```

What is the most efficient method to compare the first element of A with the first sub-list of B, compare the first element of A with the second sub-list of B, compare the third element of A with the third sub-list of B, ..., and remove the corresponding element from the sub-list in B **if** they match and the sub-list contains 2 or more elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip()` you can pair up elements from two lists:

```
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    # a is an element from A, b is a sublist from B.
```

Your sublists contain floating point values, and your list A contains strings. You'll need to figure out a tolerance for comparisons. Perhaps turning the floats to strings with the matching precision would suffice?

```
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    # a is an element from A, b is a sublist from B.
    b[:] = [i for i in b if format(i, '.4f') != a]
```

Using a slice assignment (`b[:]`) we replace the *contents* of the sublist with all elements that do not match `a` at 4 digits after the decimal.

Running that on your example input gives me:

```
[
[0.074, 0.073, 0.03, 0.029, 0.024, 0.021, 0.02], 
[0.015], 
[0.02, 0.015], 
[0.02, 0.017], 
[0.077, 0.076, 0.055, 0.045, 0.021], 
[0.053, 0.052, 0.023, 0.022], 
[]
]
```

If you only want the *first* match to be removed, use:

```
try:
    del b[next(i for i, e in enumerate(b) if format(e, '.4f') == a)]
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

This'll find the *first* index that matches, and remove that from `b`. Result (in this case exactly the same as before):

```
[[0.074, 0.073, 0.03, 0.029, 0.024, 0.021, 0.02],
 [0.015],
 [0.02, 0.015],
 [0.02, 0.017],
 [0.077, 0.076, 0.055, 0.045, 0.021],
 [0.053, 0.052, 0.023, 0.022],
 []]
```

Comment: @TingPing: Works fine for me in Python 2.7, demo output supplied.

Comment: @TingPing: Congrats, you've reached 15 points and can now vote on answers! :-P

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks for reminding me. I have up your rep by clicking on the up arrow! Woohoo!

Comment: @TingPing: Actually, there was an error in the last solution; corrected now.

Comment: There seem to be a problem with the new code too because when i run the code, it only returns the last sub-list: returns [] only. The rest of the sub-lists are gone.

Comment: @TingPing: The error I made caused the *first* element of each list to be removed, regardless.

Comment: @TingPing: Sounds like you are printing `b`, not `B`.

Comment: LOL, i got it. I mistaken a for A and b for B! Dumb me. Thanks for correcting me.